# @staticmethods calling during @classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a way to call `@staticmethod` when using `@classmethod`

```
@dataclass 
class Piza:
    ingridients: List

    @classmethod
    def make_Pizza(cls, ingrid, allerg=False):
        ingridients = ingrid
        if allerg:
            return cls(make_for_allerg(ingrid, allerg))
        return cls(ingrid)

    @staticmethod
    def make_for_allerg(ingrid, allerg):
        return ingrid.append(allerg)
```

test no allergies:

```
Piza.make_Pizza(['tomato', 'cheese'])
```

> Piza(ingridients=['tomato', 'cheese'])

test with allergies false:

```
Piza.make_Pizza(['tomato', 'cheese'], allerg='pickle')
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 Piiza.make_Piza(['tomato', 'cheese'], allerg='pickle')
>
> in make_Pizza(cls, ingrid, allerg)
>         7         ingridients = ingrid
>         8         if allerg:
>   ----> 9             return cls(make_for_allerg(ingrid, allerg))
>        10         return cls(ingrid)
>        11
>
> NameError: name 'make_for_allerg' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The staticmethod is an attribute of the class object, hence it's still namespaced by the class name. You may call it on the class object:

```
Piza.make_for_allerg(...)
```

*Note:* Your implementation is not a convincing use-case for a staticmethod.  The return value of `list.append` is always `None`.

Comment: Could you expand on using `Pizza` instead of `cls` to resolve the static method?  Not a criticism, just curious.

Comment: Not much to say - it will be possible/equivalent to resolve it on `cls` as well.  In this context, `Piza` and `cls` will just be different names bound to the same thing (it's a dataclass which is not using a multiple inheritance).